# action creator with thunk in typescript-redux, sees the action as undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have been working about 4 hours just to resolve this error:

```
export const fetchUsers: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<
  Promise<FetchUserActions>, //type of last action
  User[], // The type for the data within the last action
  null, //extra argument
  FetchUserActions
>> = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>) => {
    try {
      // ususally action creators returns an obj. but this is an api request and thunk will take over, make the request and then dispatch the res.data
      const res: AxiosResponse<User[]> = await axios.get<User[]>("/users");
      if (res && res.data) {
        return dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.fetchUsers, payload: res.data });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

I am getting those errors:

```
 Type 'Promise<{ type: ActionTypes.fetchUsers; payload: User[]; } | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<FetchUserActions>'.
 
Type '{ type: ActionTypes.fetchUsers; payload: User[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FetchUserActions'.

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FetchUserActions'.ts(2322)
```

Typescript is easy but i have hard time to understand the explanation. I dont understand where this undefined coming from.

```
export interface FetchUserActions extends Action {
  type: ActionTypes.fetchUsers;
  payload: User[];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` is because you `catch` any errors and return nothing (ie. `undefined`) when there is an error in your `axios` response.